# How to find that a file exist in Azure file share without Mounting using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, azure-devops, azure-storage-account

I was trying to find that a file exists in Azure file share. I know how to get the file by mounting the Azure file share to the machine programmatically. Is there any other way other than mounting the file share? Found there is a REST API feature of Azure file share we can utilize for this. But how to use the REST API using PowerShell

When I tried to use the below command I'm getting an error as specified.

```
   Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://test.file.core.windows.net/testartifacts/testdb/version?restype=share&comp=metadata"

   Invoke-RestMethod: InvalidQueryParameterValueValue for one of the query parameters specified in 
  the request URI is
  invalid.
```

Also how to authorize this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check below ways to get the file from Azure file share.

1, Use Azure CLI. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-cli#download-a-file).

```
az login #Log in interactively

az storage file download \
    --account-name $storageAccountName \
    --account-key $storageAccountKey \
    --share-name $shareName \
    --path "myDirectory/SampleUpload.txt" \
    --dest "SampleDownload.txt" \
    --output none
```

If you want to login using a service principal. You need to create a service principal first. See below document to create a service principal

[Use the portal to create an Azure AD application and service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal).

[Create an Azure service principal with the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#sign-in-using-a-service-principal)

And you need to add the read permission to the service principal in the role assignment of your azure story account.

Then you can [login using service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#sign-in-using-a-service-principal):

```
az login --service-principal --username APP_ID --password PASSWORD --tenant TENANT_ID

az storage file download --account-name ...
```

2, Use Azure powershell: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragefile?view=azps-5.2.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-3.3.0).

```
Connect-AzAccount  #Log in interactively

$ctx=(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccName).Context  
     
$file=Get-AZStorageFile -Context $ctx -ShareName $fileShareName -Directory directiry -Path filepath
```

You can also [sign in using service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-5.2.0#password-based-authentication).

```
$pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($sp.ApplicationId, $sp.Secret)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId
```

3, Using Azure Rest api. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file).

You can check below example to authenticate the rest api call:

```
# Variables
$TenantId = "" # Enter Tenant Id.
$ClientId = "" # Enter Service Principal Client Id.
$ClientSecret = "" # Enter Service Principal Client Secret.
$Resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/"
$SubscriptionId = "" # Enter Subscription Id.

$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/token"

$body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$ClientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret&resource=$Resource"

$Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Write-Host "Print Token" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Output $Token

# Get file
$fileUrl = "https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath/myfile"

$Headers = @{}

$Headers.Add("Authorization","$($Token.token_type) "+ " " + "$($Token.access_token)")

$file= Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $fileUrl -Headers $Headers

Write-Host "Print File" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Output $file
```

See detailed example [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53515.azure-rest-api-access-token-authentication-using-powershell-to-perform-administrative-tasks.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a file exists in Azure file share, you can use Azure File Rest API [`Get File Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file-properties). Regarding how to do auth to call the API, we can use the Shared Key authorization. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key)

For example

```
$accesskey="<storage account key>"
$storageAccount = "andyprivate"
$shareName="share2"
$filePath="test1.xml"
$date =  (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddYears(1).toString('R')
$version = "2020-04-08"

$stringToSign = "HEAD`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`nx-ms-date:$date`nx-ms-version:$version`n/$storageAccount/$shareName/$filePath"
 
$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($accesskey)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

$headers=@{"x-ms-date"=$date;
           "x-ms-version"= $version;
           "Authorization"= "SharedKey $($storageAccount):$signature"}

$url="https://$storageAccount.file.core.windows.net/$shareName/$filePath"

try{

 $res=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Head -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing
 
}catch{

  if($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ -eq 404){
   write-host "The file does not exist" -ForegroundColor Red
  }
 
}
```